# На сайте появились подозрительные ссылки вида ?rhs=xxxxxxxxxx

Tags: joomla

Заметил, что с Яндекса есть переходы на мой сайт по запросам:

```
- открытка с 1 сентября коллегам
- поздравление первоклашке девочке
- поздравления с 1 сентября крестнице
- поздравление с 1 сентября коллегам
```

И все в таком духе, хотя мой сайт совсем на другую тематику, и никогда такого контента на нем не публиковалось. Сайт работает на Joomla.

После перехода по такому запросу, открывается главная страница сайта с адресом -  `?rhs=xxxxxxxxxx`

Как найти причину и обезопасить свой сайт?

Comment: Сайт на чем сделан? Возможно переход по rhs - это уязвимость какой-то популярной CMS, и к вам лезут наобум (а вдруг сработает)

Comment: Сайт на Joomla.

Comment: С джумлой не знаком, но это баг многих систем. На сайте каким-то образом настроен редирект на страницу, указанную в параметре. Причем не осуществляется проверка, что запрос пришел с вашего сайта, а не с чужого. Возможно баг джумлы, возможно какого-то из её плагинов.

Comment: Что именно происходит? Кто-то через referer имитирует  переход на ваш сайт с поиска Яндекса на адрес главная?rhs=xxxxxxxxxx? Ну и пусть дальше имитирует. Все-таки "на сайте появились ссылки" - это несколько иная и намного более критическая ситуация. То есть в контенте самого сайта никаких новых текстов/ссылок нет? Тогда и взлома нет, а есть непонятно что, может у кого-то с ошибкой работает Referrer Spam скрипт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала архив сайта на локалку и пройтись [айболитом](http://revisium.com/ai/). 
Ручками вычистить шеллы и прочую дрянь.
Установить последние заплатки или последнюю версию жумлы и используемых компонентов.
Потом проверить зарегистрированых пользователей с правами выше гостевых.
Внимательно курить вот [эту](http://joomlaforum.ru/index.php/topic,195980.570.html) тему.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить антивирусом на хостинге, если есть. Если нет - локально.

Также сменить пароли на всякий случай везде. база, админка.

В крайнем случае, восстановить бэкап, если ничего не поможет.

Если почистите, то обязательно усилить безопасноть, перенести адрес админки на другой урл и поставить внутренний антивирус.